# Can't Debug into Source Code

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse-cdt on Kepler on Ubuntu 14.10

I have a program that is calling some third-party software.  I have the source code for this software but the code for this software is compiled outside of eclipse using make.

When I try to single step into the third party software I get this error message "No source available for "foo()""

I have gone into Debug Configurations and set the C++ Remote Application->Source and added a 'File System Directory' that points to the directory the c files exist in, but I still get the same error.

I verified that the third-party software was compiled with the -g option on; but still I can not get this to work.

How do I get eclipse to show the source code for this third-party software?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to import the existing code as a new project.

First import the project using File->Import... then in the left-hand column, 
expand the C/C++ item and select 'Existing Code as Makefile Project'  Give the project a name and select the existing code location, then click Finish.  You should now have a new project in the Project Explorer that you can use to browse the source.

Next right click on the existing project that you are trying to debug and choose 'Properties'  In the left-hand pane select 'Project References' then check off the new project that you just imported.

You should now be able to step into (or create breakpoints within) the 3rdparty code.  As an added bonus, you will now be able to re-build the 3rdparty code from within eclipse if needed.